# What exactly does 'window.location.replace' do / how to replicate it in mechanize?

Tags: javascript, forms, http, post, mechanize

I'm interfacing with a site that implements delaying a page-load with client-side JavaScript. Basically, a form is submitted on `PageA.asp`, and instead of the data going to `PageB.asp`, it goes to `PageC.asp`. `PageC.asp` consists of a 'please wait' message along with the following JavaScript:

```
function OnTimer() {
    window.location.replace("PageB.asp");
    return;
}
setTimeout('OnTimer()', 10000);
```

The interesting thing here is that when `PageB.asp` loads, it somehow has all the information submitted from `PageA.asp`. Yet whenever I've looked up whether you can pass POST data along with `window.location.replace`, the answer has been "no".

So how does `PageB.asp` have the data from `PageA.asp` even though it was loaded from `PageC.asp`? Does `window.location.replace` load the new page with the same POST data? How would I best re-implement this in mechanize: remember the POST data from `PageA.asp` and submit the form with the action being `PageB.asp` instead of `PageC.asp`?

Comment: Maybe it's simply stored in the database and associated with the session, so that *any* page on that site can get it when it needs it.

Comment: I thought of that, but I tried doing `mech.open("PageB.asp")` at that point in my code and the data wasn't transferred.